# rewrite after rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i have:

1. nginx server
2. site based on joomla
3. rewrite like this in server block

   ```
   location / {
       # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
   ```

this produces "sef like" links /abb/aaa/ccc

what i want now is to make map of short url's (of those rewrite links)

like this:

```
map @rewrite_url $rewrited_url {
    /a    /abb/aaa/ccc
    /b    /aaa/adddd/aaa
}
```

and this map to be applied

**edit:**

in location / try_files this :

```
/index.php?q=$request_uri;
```

makes joomla url:

```
/index.php?bla=1&blab=2  ===> like "/aaa/aaa/aaa"  - > without  ?,& and =
```

and i wanna make short form of this friendly(s) link(s) as include map to use:

```
/a instead of /bla/bla/comelink
/b instead of /bla/aaa/someotherlink
```

example (alias):

```
/changelog  /some/adres/to change-log/on/joomla/page
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve - why do you want a map? Do you have rewrites you haven't shown? What is a "sef like"? Why do you think try_files is producing URLs that look like that - I'm not sure they are, based on what you've said.

Comment: @tim see edit :)

Comment: So would you say your problem is that your application generates redirects, and you'd like to hard code those redirects to reduce delays and increase performance?

Comment: @tim yes and to simplify users life not to remember long url's (and because its 
permanent address - i know it will not change over time)

Comment: I assume you read Nginx documentation and tutorials online. Show us what you did and what went wrong. Right now it seems like you want us to do your job, this is a fairly basic task.

Answer (score 0):

ok i manage to track down why it was not working it was a spelling in rewrite map base url

solution to my problem is:

```
#redirect.map file content 
/target /destination/link;

#nginx http + server block 
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    include snippets/redirect.map;
}

server {

    location $reguest_uri  {
        if ($new_uri) {
           return 301 $new_uri;
        } 
    }

}
```